# Need to set default thumbnail image if the image is not uploaded or not set

Tags: php, wordpress

i am working in a classified site..if a user has uploaded image it displays thumbnail but i want to add a default thumbnail image if image is not uploaded..i am new to php and am not able to code it in wp template..Thank You

```
            View File

            <div class="thumb">
            <?php

            colabs_image('key=image&width=150&height=154');

            ?>
            </div> 

            function colabs_image($args) {

            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            /* SET VARIABLES $key = get_option('colabs_custom_field_image');*/
            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

            global $post;
            global $colabs_options;

            //Defaults
            if (get_option('colabs_custom_field_image')!=''){

              $key = '<img border="0" src="http://mmpropertydevelopers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/thumbnail-default.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />';
            }else{
                $key = 'image';

            }
            $width = null;
            $height = null;
            $class = '';
            $quality = 90;
            $id = null;
            $link = 'src';
            $repeat = 1;
            $offset = 0;
            $before = '';
            $after = '';
            $single = false;
            $force = true;
            $return = false;
            $is_auto_image = false;
            $src = '';
            $meta = '';
            $alignment = '';
            $size = ''; 
            $play = false;
            $alt = '';
            $img_link = '';

            $attachment_id = array();
            $attachment_src = array();

            if ( !is_array($args) ) 
                parse_str( $args, $args );

            extract($args);

            // Set Play Icon
            $playicon = '';

            // Set post ID
            if ( empty($id) ) {
                $id = $post->ID;
            }

            $thumb_id = get_post_meta($id,'_thumbnail_id',true);

            // Set alignment 
            if ( '' == $alignment) 
                $alignment = get_post_meta($id, '_image_alignment', true);

            // Get standard sizes
            if ( !$width && !$height ) {
                $width = '100';
                $height = '100';
            }

            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            /* FIND IMAGE TO USE */
            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

            // When a custom image is sent through
            if ( $src != '' ) { 
                $custom_field = $src;
                $link = 'img';

            // WP 2.9 Post Thumbnail support    
            } elseif ( 'true' == get_option( 'colabs_post_image_support') AND !empty($thumb_id) ) {

                if ( get_option( 'colabs_pis_resize') == "true") {

                    // Dynamically resize the post thumbnail 
                    $vt_crop = get_option( 'colabs_pis_hard_crop' );
                    if ($vt_crop == "true") $vt_crop = true; else $vt_crop = false;
                    $vt_image = vt_resize( $thumb_id, '', $width, $height, $vt_crop );

                    // Set fields for output
                    $custom_field = $vt_image['url'];       
                    $width = $vt_image['width'];
                    $height = $vt_image['height'];

                } else {
                    // Use predefined size string
                    if ( $size ) 
                        $thumb_size = $size;
                    else 
                        $thumb_size = array($width,$height);

                    $img_link = get_the_post_thumbnail($id,$thumb_size,array( 'class' => 'colabs-image ' . $class));
                }       

            // Grab the image from custom field
            } else {
                $custom_field = get_post_meta($id, $key, true);
            } 

            // Automatic Image Thumbs - get first image from post attachment
            if ( empty($custom_field) && 'true' == get_option( 'colabs_auto_img') && empty($img_link) && !(is_singular() AND in_the_loop() AND $link == "src") ) { 

                if( $offset >= 1 ) 
                    $repeat = $repeat + $offset;

                $attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $id,
                                                    'numberposts' => $repeat,
                                                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                                    'order' => 'DESC', 
                                                    'orderby' => 'menu_order date')
                                                    );

                // Search for and get the post attachment
                if ( !empty($attachments) ) {  

                    $counter = -1;
                    $size = 'large';
                    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {            
                        $counter++;
                        if ( $counter < $offset ) 
                            continue;

                        if ( 'true' == get_option('colabs_post_image_support') AND get_option( 'colabs_pis_resize') == "true") {

                            // Dynamically resize the post thumbnail 
                            $vt_crop = get_option( 'colabs_pis_hard_crop' );
                            if ($vt_crop == "true") $vt_crop = true; else $vt_crop = false;
                            $vt_image = vt_resize( $att_id, '', $width, $height, $vt_crop );

                            // Set fields for output
                            $custom_field = $vt_image['url'];       
                            $width = $vt_image['width'];
                            $height = $vt_image['height'];

                        } else {

                            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att_id, $size, true);
                            $custom_field = $src[0];
                            $attachment_id[] = $att_id;
                            $src_arr[] = $custom_field;

                        }
                        $thumb_id = $att_id;
                        $is_auto_image = true;
                    }

                // Get the first img tag from content
                } else { 

                    $first_img = '';
                    $post = get_post($id); 
                    ob_start();
                    ob_end_clean();
                    $output = preg_match_all( '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
                    if ( !empty($matches[1][0]) ) {

                        // Save Image URL
                        $custom_field = $matches[1][0];

                        // Search for ALT tag
                        $output = preg_match_all( '/<img.+alt=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
                        if ( !empty($matches[1][0]) ) {
                            $alt = $matches[1][0];
                        }
                    }

                }

            } 

            // Check if there is YouTube embed
            if ( empty($custom_field) && empty($img_link) ) {
                $embed = get_post_meta($id, "colabs_embed", true);
                if ( $embed ) {
                    $custom_field = colabs_get_video_image($embed);

                    // Set Play Icon
                    if($play == true){ $playicon = '<span class="playicon">Play</span>'; }

                    }
            }

            // Return if there is no attachment or custom field set
            if ( empty($custom_field) && empty($img_link) ) {

                // Check if default placeholder image is uploaded
                $placeholder = get_option( 'framework_colabs_default_image' );
                if ( $placeholder && !(is_singular() AND in_the_loop()) ) {
                    $custom_field = $placeholder;   

                    // Resize the placeholder if
                    if ( 'true' == get_option('colabs_post_image_support') AND get_option( 'colabs_pis_resize') == "true") {

                        // Dynamically resize the post thumbnail 
                        $vt_crop = get_option( 'colabs_pis_hard_crop' );
                        if ($vt_crop == "true") $vt_crop = true; else $vt_crop = false;
                        $vt_image = vt_resize( '', $placeholder, $width, $height, $vt_crop );

                        // Set fields for output
                        $custom_field = $vt_image['url'];       
                        $width = $vt_image['width'];
                        $height = $vt_image['height'];

                    }           

                } else {
                   return;

                }

            }

            if(empty($src_arr) && empty($img_link)){ $src_arr[] = $custom_field; }

            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
            /* BEGIN OUTPUT */
            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

            $output = '';

            // Set output height and width
            $set_width = ' width="' . $width .'" ';
            $set_height = ' height="' . $height .'" '; 
            if($height == null OR '' == $height) $set_height = '';

            // Set standard class
            if ( $class ) $class = 'colabs-image ' . $class; else $class = 'colabs-image';

            // Do check to verify if images are smaller then specified.
            if($force == true){ $set_width = ''; $set_height = ''; }

            // WP Post Thumbnail
            if(!empty($img_link) ){

                if( 'img' == $link ) {  // Output the image without anchors
                    $output .= $before; 
                    $output .= $img_link;
                    $output .= $after;  

                } elseif( 'url' == $link ) {  // Output the large image

                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'large', true);
                    $custom_field = $src[0];
                    $output .= $custom_field;

                } else {  // Default - output with link             

                    if ( ( is_single() OR is_page() ) AND $single == false ) {
                        $rel = 'rel="lightbox"';
                        $href = false;  
                    } else { 
                        $href = get_permalink($id);
                        $rel = '';
                    }

                    $title = 'title="' . get_the_title($id) .'"';

                    $output .= $before; 
                    if($href == false){
                        $output .= $img_link;
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<a '.$title.' href="' . $href .'" '.$rel.'>' . $img_link .  '</a>';
                    }

                    $output .= $after;  
                }   
            }

            // Use thumb.php to resize. Skip if image has been natively resized with vt_resize.
            elseif ( 'true' == get_option( 'colabs_resize') && empty($vt_image['url']) ) { 

                foreach($src_arr as $key => $custom_field){

                    // Clean the image URL
                    $href = $custom_field;      
                    $custom_field = cleanSource( $custom_field );

                    // Check if WPMU and set correct path AND that image isn't external
                    if ( function_exists( 'get_current_site') && strpos($custom_field,"http://") !== 0 ) {
                        get_current_site();
                        //global $blog_id; Breaks with WP3 MS
                        if ( !$blog_id ) {
                            global $current_blog;
                            $blog_id = $current_blog->blog_id;              
                        }
                        if ( isset($blog_id) && $blog_id > 0 ) {
                            $imageParts = explode( 'files/', $custom_field );
                            if ( isset($imageParts[1]) ) 
                                $custom_field = '/blogs.dir/' . $blog_id . '/files/' . $imageParts[1];
                        }
                    }

                    //Set the ID to the Attachment's ID if it is an attachment
                    if($is_auto_image == true){ 
                        $quick_id = $attachment_id[$key];
                    } else {
                        $quick_id = $id;
                    }

                    //Set custom meta 
                    if ($meta) { 
                        $alt = $meta;
                        $title = 'title="'. $meta .'"';
                    } else { 
                        if ('' == $alt AND get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ) 
                            $alt = get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                        else
                            $alt = get_the_title($quick_id);
                        $title = 'title="'. get_the_title($quick_id) .'"';
                    }

                    // Set alignment parameter
                    if ($alignment <> '')
                        $alignment = '&amp;a='.$alignment;

                    $img_link = '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri(). '/functions/timthumb.php?src='. $custom_field .'&amp;w='. $width .'&amp;h='. $height .'&amp;zc=1&amp;q='. $quality . $alignment . '" alt="'.$alt.'" class="'. stripslashes($class) .'" '. $set_width . $set_height . ' />';

                    if( 'img' == $link ) {  // Just output the image
                        $output .= $before; 
                        $output .= $img_link;
                        $output .= $playicon;
                        $output .= $after;  

                    } elseif( 'url' == $link ) {  // Output the image without anchors

                        if($is_auto_image == true){ 
                            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'large', true);
                            $custom_field = $src[0];
                        }
                        $output .= $custom_field;

                    } else {  // Default - output with link             

                        if ( ( is_single() OR is_page() ) AND $single == false ) {
                            $rel = 'rel="lightbox"';
                        } else { 
                            $href = get_permalink($id);
                            $rel = '';
                        }

                        $output .= $before; 
                        $output .= '<a '.$title.' href="' . $href .'" '.$rel.'>' . $img_link . $playicon . '</a>';
                        $output .= $after;  
                    }
                }

            // No dynamic resizing
            } else {  

                foreach($src_arr as $key => $custom_field){

                    //Set the ID to the Attachment's ID if it is an attachment
                    if($is_auto_image == true AND isset($attachment_id[$key])){ 
                        $quick_id = $attachment_id[$key];
                    } else {
                        $quick_id = $id;
                    }

                    //Set custom meta 
                    if ($meta) { 
                        $alt = $meta;
                        $title = 'title="'. $meta .'"';
                    } else { 
                        if ('' == $alt) $alt = get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                        $title = 'title="'. get_the_title($quick_id) .'"';
                    }

                    $img_link =  '<img src="'. $custom_field .'" alt="'. $alt .'" '. $set_width . $set_height . ' class="'. stripslashes($class) .'" />';

                    if ( 'img' == $link ) {  // Just output the image 
                        $output .= $before;                   
                        $output .= $img_link; 
                        $output .= $after;  

                    } elseif( 'url' == $link ) {  // Output the URL to original image
                        if ( $vt_image['url'] || $is_auto_image ) { 
                            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
                            $custom_field = $src[0];
                        }
                        $output .= $custom_field;

                    } else {  // Default - output with link

                        if ( ( is_single() OR is_page() ) AND $single == false ) { 

                            // Link to the large image if single post
                            if ( $vt_image['url'] || $is_auto_image ) { 
                                $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
                                $custom_field = $src[0];
                            }

                            $href = $custom_field;
                            $rel = 'rel="lightbox"';
                        } else { 
                            $href = get_permalink($id);
                            $rel = '';
                        }

                        $output .= $before;   
                        $output .= '<a href="' . $href .'" '. $rel . $title .'>' . $img_link  . '</a>';
                        $output .= $after;   
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return or echo the output
            if ( $return == TRUE )
                return $output;
            else 
                echo $output; // Done  

        }

        /* Get thumbnail from Video Embed code */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a javascript `onError` to the picture.

```
$key = '<img border="0" src="mypic.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100"
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='.chr(39).'alternative.jpg'.chr(39).'"/>';
```